# Why is magento so slow? Wait up to 35 seconds

Tags: magento-1.9

Magento gives a very late response. Wait up to 35 seconds.

The server where it is hosted serves other non-Magento sites super fast. What is it about the PHP code that Magento uses that makes it so slow, and what can be done to fix it?
also, I use MaxCDN for media files

Comment: use profiler https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Profiler, you have some issues with extension.

Comment: Magento isn't slow. What you do with Magento makes it slow - inappropriate hosting and badly written code.

Answer (score 3):

Use a competent web hosting service that optimizes their servers to run Magento.

Provide Magento with enough resources (system with plenty of memory and fast disk subsystem IO) to run properly.

Don't run Magento on shared hosting services unless you have a tiny boutique site that sees little traffic and if so, then only with a hosting service that understands Magento resource requirements and doesn't massively overprovision the number of websites hosted per server.

Magento is very resource intensive and one of the most complex PHP applications you are going to come across. It needs MySQL to be tuned for performance and the web server engine and PHP must be configured for best efficiency.

[How to determine hosting requirements](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/43907/how-to-determine-hosting-requirements)

Answer (score 0):

### [Edited]

**Magento is one of the biggest PHP Oop application of current time**.

*For  your issue ,i  am suggest you follow below option*

### Check Magento memory usage

Just a few questions about things that can help with TTFB. You can use the Magento Profiler, or try using the [AOE Profiler](https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Profiler) as another approach. You can also use something like Xdebug.

### Debug code:

Another thing to try is in a dev instance try disabling some modules and see if any of them cause the TTFB to improve drastically. Or change the theme and see if that makes a big difference. Hopefully you can narrow down the culprit.

See details at http://www.atwix.com/magento/finding-bottlenecks/

Comment: Caching doesn't improve performance.