# Hardware requirements for a multi-tenant or Multi domain magento installation

Tags: magento-2.1, server-setup, multidomain

I am exploring to replicate the multi-tenant model using Magento. Currently, I am looking at how to select and the hardware as we scale. Based on my guestimation I would have the following

- 500 Magento installations / Instances
- 550,000 SKUs
- 21,633 average visitors per day
- 56,600 maximum visitors per day

What type of CPU would I require for this?

As per my calculations, I would require, 14 x 12Core @2.3Ghz

Please help.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

There is no such formula for calculating number of CPUs you need. There are many factors which contribute to the needed server power.

- Code quality (in terms of performance)
- Cache utilization
- Average number of visitors
- ...

Those factors are so different from case to case. Also, keep in mind that you'll have different server utilization depending on part of the day. That's why it's good to have servers set up on AWS where you can make auto-scaling groups, and scale servers as your needs grew.

ref: [AWS Autoscaling Groups](https://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/)

Also, it's not all about the number of servers, it's also about the architecture. Take a look at this example on [Magento using Amazon](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/magento/images/magento-architecture.png) .

For example, if you're scaling frontend servers only, at some point, it will happen that your database is the bottleneck.

What I can suggest to you is to start with one configuration/architecture, and then to measure results. You can do stress tests in order to find out what are limits of yours architecture. Then you can identify the bottleneck, and work on it to increase its throughput.

- [Flood.Io](https://flood.io/)
- [Blitz.Io](https://www.blitz.io/)
- JMeter

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sinisa. The formula I used to calculate the CPU required was on the basis of another article I read on this forum (http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/43907/how-to-determine-hosting-requirements). So I am still confused, what to do

Comment: Those numbers are related to the hosting solution provided by [Sonassi](https://www.sonassi.com/), so they can tell you approximate resources needed if you run Magento on their hosting, with their configuration based on their experience. So, the best thing you can do is to consult them about resources needed, if you plan to use Sonassi.

If you plan to host it on your own,  then it's not possible to approximate number of servers because there are too many variables, as you can see in the post you've mentioned, too.