# Decrease TTFB on Magento 1.9 store with 600k SKUs

Tags: magento-1.9, database, performance, server-setup

We recently have jumped our total number of SKUs from ~5,000 to ~600,000 on our Magento 1.9 store. There will be a chance for us to increase these numbers in the near future, but we need to nail down fixes for our performance issues first.

Currently we're hosting our PHP on an AWS instance with Cpanel installed. Our database is contained by itself on an RDS T2.Large instance (8gb RAM 2vCPU).

We get about 100-200 pageviews per day but this will probably increase quite a bit, but when a customer does a search they're getting TTFB times of around 5 seconds.

What sort of specs do we need to get a faster performing database with this total number of SKUs? This is a question that assumes total traffic to the site will not increase.

What are the questions I should be asking to get the answers I need?

Are there any case studies available for Magento 1x websites that had roughly this amount of SKUs or more?

Answer (score 1):

The answer in this question: [how to determine hosting requirements](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/43907/how-to-determine-hosting-requirements) should help you. It is important to understand there is no real hard line answer, it can be different per website. There are so many variables that affect performance, I suggest you get a specialist in to optimise your infrastructure.