# magento 2 hosting suggestion?

Tags: hosting

I need a magento 2 web site for European customers, the products will be about 1000, and I am a chinese, so I need it can be visit from china fast, so please give me a suggestion about hosting provider and hosting plan, does 2 Core 4 GB should be ok?

Comment: 2 Core and 4 GB will not be enough. Please have a look at this answer, you will get the better understanding.  https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/43916/48571

Answer (score 1):

How about your daily traffic and number of concurrent users?
With 1000 products, I suggest to use at least 4 core 4 gb ram for a stable website because Magento 2 requires at least 2gb ram to run smoothly.
I found a magento 2 hosting performance review that may help here: https://magenhosting.com/best-magento-2-hosting
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For high traffic and number of users analysis and with 1000 products. At least 4gb core and 4gb ram are required for Magento 2 site, as it would be enough for the speed of your store.

Also, for Magento 2 hosting performance and speed issues, you should go with Managed hosting with Magento.

For Managed magento hosting, you may be free from the hassles of the setup process and speed so that they can handle it for you.

One of the providers you may consider is Cloiudways.